# TypeError: parser.destructuringAssignmentPropertiesFor is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, storybook

Does anyone know how to update the webpack to run the storybook?

I am getting an issue while running storybook in ReactJs project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrnD0.png)

I am running it on nodejs 14.20.0 and the storybook version is 6.5.16